# IE8 PNG Gradient Transparency Problem

Tags: html, internet-explorer, png

The following graphic illustrates an issue with png transparency in Internet Explorer, that I am unable to resolve.

[Transparancy not so transparent in Redmond. http://img101.imageshack.us/img101/1917/problemkl.jpg](http://img101.imageshack.us/img101/1917/problemkl.jpg)

The transparent graphic is the following image.

http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/7959/transparentfade.png

I realize that it might be invisible on white background, so here's the inverse of the same image to aid understanding.

http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/7121/transparentfadeinverse.png

The idea is to provide a soft lead-out which works nicely on Chrome/FF/Safari/Whathaveyou, but obviously one can't have nice things and IE wants to stand out. I would very much appreciate any help on this matter.

**EDIT:** I've read someplace that combining opacity effects and transparent pngs is not well supported in Internet Explorer. By removing the opacity effect and making suitable changes to my png graphic, I was able to reproduce same animation across all major browsers.

Comment: You might want to post the markup so we can look at it *in situ*

Comment: what did you use to make the image?

Comment: png8 or 24? If 24 you're going to need to use a Javascript png fix. If 8 you should import into Fireworks and export as an alpha transparency png8 file.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot safely mix legacy DirectX Opacity Filters and transparent-PNGs. In IE9, you can use native CSS3 Opacity safely with PNGs without the problem you encountered.